# iPhone app does not run on old device (3G, 3GS, ...)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, usb, iphone-3gs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)

I have developed an app which works on iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3 & 5) (which used during developing). Now I have tried to test on 3GS (iOS 4.3.3) and 3G(iOS 4.2). But app does not load into these devices. I can see following messages on consol when try to deploy to device.

```
Sat Jan  1 17:27:38 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: 
            Could not receive USB message #6 from Xcode. Killing connection 
Sat Jan  1 17:27:38 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[16] <Notice>: Could not 
            receive size of message
```

I have tested on Xcode 4.0.2 as well as 4.2 beta. Restarted devices and MAC but still same. Can anybody know about this issue?
Thanks

Comment: This issue has been solved after using Xcode 3.2.5. Once I have build with Xcode 3.2.5, I could deploy app on 3GS and 3G without any issue. Thanks for viewing my question.

Comment: This has been closed in favor of the newer question, which was better asked and received better answers.

Comment: I wish it wasn't closed, the newer question is not a duplicate.  I have this problem, however if I run the app from the device, it runs, so it is installed OK, the certs and profile must be fine, and it can't be an architecture problem.

Some people elsewhere on the net suggest that this could be a jailbreak problem, but I don't think my phone is jail broken.

I don't have enough rep to re-open though.

Comment: The problem was I have added some features which iPhone 3 does not has to plist. When I removed those, it worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can come for various reasons. Until now this is are the cases pople have encountered:

- bad cable -> try another one, or hold it really still when programming
- unsuported features mentioned in info.plist -> check plist
- unsuported architecture (by default Xcode4.2 uses standard arch= armv7 ) -> add armv6

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I did add armv6 in the project settings, but armv7 was mentioned as required in info.plist. I removed it (and re-inserted the cable), and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check your cable or your device dock. The problem in your console says your material connection is not healthy. Can you perform an itunes synchronization ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have solved the issues. That was not because of physical things. I have added following values to plist.

`<array>
  <string>gps</string>
  <string>location-services</string>
  <string>front-facing-camera</string>
 </array>`

3GS phone does not support front-facing-camera. So after I remove that part, I could install my app on 3GS.

Answer (score -1):

Check the frameworks used by you... mostlt it happen that a some of frameworks doesn't work for old devices so they should not be of **REQUIRED** type but of **OPTIONAL**. Hope it works for you.